# Foreach loop stripping all data from result

Tags: php, foreach

In the code below I have created a blacklist of e-mails that I would like to remove however I am getting an empty array when I run with `if(stripos($row->guestEmail, $b))`

If I remove the `stripos` and run with the basic if statement `if($row->guestEmail)` it shows all of the data including e-mail address's that are not in the `$blacklist`.

Why is the blacklist foreach stripping all of the data?

```
$guests = [];
$emails = [];
$blacklist = ['@booking.com', 'N/A', 'n.c@nc.com', 'n.c@nc.com'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');

foreach ($results->data as $row) {
    $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;
    foreach ($blacklist as $b) {
        if (stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) !== false && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->endDate)) == $date) {

            $guests[] = array(
                'FirstName' => $row->guestFirstName,
                'LastName' => $row->guestLastName,
                'email' => $row->guestEmail,
                'country' => $row->guestCountry,
                'check-in_date' => $row->startDate,
                'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) !== false` this is true if this guest's email *IS* blacklisted. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Weltschmerz correct - should not appear in final result

Comment: and what holds final results?

Comment: @Weltschmerz $guests[]

Comment: In that basic if statement you wrote do you also include second evaluation (concerning the date)?

Comment: @AbbasAkhundov Yes correct that part works fine its just the e-mail part thats being annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$guests = [];
$emails = [];
$blacklist = ['@booking.com', 'N/A', 'n.c@nc.com', 'n.c@nc.com'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');

foreach ($results->data as $row) {
    $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;

    //check for all blacklist flags
    $blackListed = false;
    foreach ($blacklist as $b) {
        if (stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) !== false) {
            $blackListed = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    //if all pass and date is good, we're good
    if (!$blackListed && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->endDate)) == $date) {
        $guests[] = array(
            'FirstName' => $row->guestFirstName,
            'LastName' => $row->guestLastName,
            'email' => $row->guestEmail,
            'country' => $row->guestCountry,
            'check-in_date' => $row->startDate,
            'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes utter sense will try within next 10min :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$guests = [];
$emails = [];
$blacklist = ['@booking.com', 'N/A', 'n.c@nc.com', 'n.c@nc.com'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');

foreach ($results->data as $row) {
    $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;
    foreach ($blacklist as $b) {
        if (stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) === false && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->endDate)) == $date) {

            $guests[] = array(
                'FirstName' => $row->guestFirstName,
                'LastName' => $row->guestLastName,
                'email' => $row->guestEmail,
                'country' => $row->guestCountry,
                'check-in_date' => $row->startDate,
                'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Problem was in

```
stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) !== false
```

This condition is the opposite of what you need.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using **=== false**. **stripos** function may return value which evaluates to **false** but is not false.

Comment: It doesn't work still shows all the e-mails within the result but also duplicates too

Comment: @JessMcKenzie  change condition to this stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) === false